# iOS custom font shows on simulator, but does not show on device

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I am using a custom font in my iOS application

```
//Label which will display the current message
currentMessageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 75, 300, 30)];
[currentMessageLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
currentMessageLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baroque Script" size:24];
currentMessageLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
currentMessageLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubivew:currentMessageLabel];
```

I have added the font name to the Info.plist file, copied the file to the bundle resources manually. And it works on the simulator, but when I run the app on iPhone 5, it does not show up at all. How do I fix this ?

Comment: I would try deleting the app from your phone and then reinstalling it

Comment: I tried that as well. Didn't work

Comment: is the simulator ios version same as the phone?

Comment: Yes. its the iPhone 6.0 simulator and iPhone 5

Comment: The simulator is not case sensitive, but the device is. Try double-checking the letters and casing.

Comment: It seems to be alright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the name from

```
@"Baroque Script"
```

to

```
@"BaroqueScript"
```

(without space).

I had similar problems and was solved by doing this.
Probably or probably will not work for you. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because  your font was not copied to your project(but referenced). So when you run through device it cannot find the font which is on your computer somewhere.

Do these steps 
1)Delete your font from project.
2)drag and drop onto your project and check copy items and add to targets .

If you can't understand the above process. Have a look at http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/using-custom-fonts-in-ios-application/ and check out the adding fonts to your project section.

Answer (score 0):

Man ,this will print all font names, u just need to copy exact font name

NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];

```
NSArray *fontNames;
NSInteger indFamily, indFont;
for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
{
    NSLog(@"Family name: %@", [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]);
    fontNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:
                 [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:
                  [familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily]]];
    for (indFont=0; indFont<[fontNames count]; ++indFont)
    {
        NSLog(@"    Font name: %@", [fontNames objectAtIndex:indFont]);
    }
}
```